# SQL Select from two tables, get null values for columns if WHERE clause is false

Tags: mysql, sql

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfd41ef/1

I want to get every row from table **person** and if the clause WHERE is false I want to get null values. Is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE `pet` (
    `owner_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pet_type` ENUM('DOG','CAT') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pet_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `person` (
    `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO `person` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
    (1, 'qwe', 'asd'),
    (2, 'asd', 'fgh'),
    (3, 'zxc', 'vbn');

INSERT INTO `pet` (`owner_id`, `pet_type`, `pet_name`) VALUES
    (1, 'DOG', 'rex');

SELECT person.*, pet.pet_name FROM person LEFT JOIN pet ON person.id = pet.owner_id WHERE pet.pet_type = 'DOG'
```

Thank you Lukasz Szozda and Yogesh Sharma for your answer moving the condition to ON does what I wanted

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and include the query you are using. If the external site is down for some reason, people are not able to see your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move condition to `ON`:

```
SELECT person.*, pet.pet_name 
FROM person 
LEFT JOIN pet 
  ON person.id = pet.owner_id
 AND pet.pet_type = 'DOG';
```

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfd41ef/5/0)**

Answer (score 4):

Move to  `ON` clause instead of going with `where` clause :

```
SELECT person.*, pet.pet_name 
FROM person LEFT JOIN 
     pet 
     ON person.id = pet.owner_id and pet.pet_type = 'DOG';
```

You `where` clause turns into `inner join` which is the problem.

Comment: The `where` clause doesn't turn into an `inner join`, it will still return the initial same results as the `left join` without the `where`. It then just filters the records out so the final results are the same as they would have been with the `inner join`. It's semantics, but still a more proper description of what the query is doing. Also, using the `ON` should be more efficient.